# Access constants inside namespace with a dynamic name

Tags: php, namespaces

Lets say i have 2 php files with namespaces :

The first:

```
# src/one.php
namespace foo\one;

const SOME_VALUE = "value 1";
```

And the second:

```
# src/two.php
namespace foo\two;

const SOME_VALUE = "value 2";
```

What i am trying to do :

```
require_once "src/one.php";
require_once "src/two.php";

foreach(["one", "two"] as $ns_type) {
    echo foo\$ns_type\SOME_VALUE;
}
```

Obviously it does not work like that. I have been reading the doc's and could
not find the right way to do this.

The only solution i found is to add a function to each namespace, construct a string with it's name and then call it.

```
$func = "foo\$ns_name\get_my_constant";
$func();
```

So the question remains, how can i access namespaced constants without a helper function ?
P.S *constant names are same for each file*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to print constant value by it's dynamic name, you can try this:

```
echo constant("foo\\$ns_type\SOME_VALUE");
```

in your foreach loop.